# Error in smart contract solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, truffle-contract, truffle-compile

Hello i have some problem when i compile my smart contract with truffle
i use the network of truffle develop

Truffle v5.1.14-nodeLTS.0 (core: 5.1.13)

Solidity - ^0.4.0 (solc-js)

Node v13.1.0

Web3.js v1.2.1

the message of the error is :(ParserError: Expected ',' but got identifier) here you are the capture of my console
[image]

thank you in advance for your answers and here is my code,

```
    pragma solidity 0.6.8;
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

import "./../installed_contracts/zeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";

contract Marketplace {

 using SafeMath for uint;

    struct User {
        uint reputation;
        string name;
        bool isUser;
    }

    struct Request {
            address company;
            uint id;
            uint deadline; //delai
            uint startTime;
            uint miniReputation;
            uint remuneration;
            string description;
            string url;
            State state;
            mapping(address=>bool) accepted;
            mapping(address=>bool) candidates;
    }

    address owner;
    mapping (address => uint) public balances;
    mapping(address => User) public users;
    mapping(uint => Request) public requests;
   // mapping(uint=>mapping(address=>bool))public candidates;


    uint requestCount;
    uint decimal=100;
    uint cost=102;

    enum State{OPENED,ONGOING,CLOSED}

    event UserCreated(address _add,uint _reputation, string  _name, bool _isUser);
    event RequestCreated(address _add, uint _id, uint _deadline, uint _startTime,
    uint _miniReputation, uint _cost, string _description,
    string _url, State _state);
    event Application(uint _id,address _add,uint _reputation);
    event OfferAccepted(uint _id,address _add);

    constructor() public{
        owner = msg.sender;
        requestCount;
    }

   modifier requestState 
        (uint _id, State _state)
        {
            require(requests[_id].state==_state,"request is not accessible");
            _;
        }

    modifier nextRequestState
        (uint _id, State _state)
        {
            updateState(_id, _state);
         _;

        }

    modifier isUser
        (address _add)
        {
            require(_add!=address(0),"You are the 0 address");
            require(users[_add].isUser,"You are not a user !");
            _;
        }

    modifier isRequest
        (uint _id)
        {
            require(requests[_id].id > 0,"The request does not exist !");
            _;
        }


    modifier isCandidate
        (uint _id,address _add)
        {
            require(_add!=address(0),"You are the 0 address");
            require(requests[_id].candidates[_add],"You are not a candidate !");
            _;
        }


    modifier isCompany
        (uint _id)
        {
            require(msg.sender!=address(0),"You are the 0 address");
            require(requests[_id].company!=msg.sender,"You are the company !");
            _;
        }

    modifier isAccepted
        (uint _id,address _add)
        {
            require(_add!=address(0),"You are the 0 address");
            require(requests[_id].accepted[_add],"You are not accepted !");
            _;
        }

    modifier isInTime
    (uint _id)
    {
      require(requests[_id].startTime<=now && requests[_id].deadline>=now,"You are not in time");  
      _;
    }

    modifier afterDeadline
    (uint _id)
    {
        require(requests[_id].deadline < now,"The deadline is not reached !");
        _;
    }

    function  updateState(uint _id,State _state) internal{
        requests[_id].state = _state;
    }

//s'inscrire
    function inscription (string memory _name, uint _reputation) 
    public 
    {
        require(!users[msg.sender].isUser, "You are already user !");
        require(bytes(_name).length>0,"the name is not valid");
        require(_reputation>=1,"the reputation is not valid");
        User memory newUser = User(_reputation,_name,true);
        users[msg.sender] = newUser;
        emit UserCreated(msg.sender,_reputation,_name,true);
    }

    //ajouter demande
    function addRequest
    (string calldata _description,
    uint _miniReputation,
    uint _deadline,
    uint _remuneration)
    external
    payable
    isUser(msg.sender)
    {
        //verifier qu'on a bien une description 
        require(bytes(_description).length>0,"The description is not valid !");
        //verifier que la reputation est sup à 1
        require(_miniReputation>1,"miniReputation is not valid");
        //verifier que la durée est bien plus superieur à 0
        require(_deadline>0,"The deadline is not valid");
        //verifier si on a assez de Wei
        uint _amount = (_remuneration.mul(cost)).div(decimal);
        require(msg.value >= _amount,"not enough of Wei");
        requestCount++;
        balances [owner]=balances [owner].add(msg.value);
       uint deadline = _deadline * 1 days;
       Request memory newRequest = Request(msg.sender,requestCount,deadline,0,_miniReputation,_remuneration,_description,"",State.OPENED);
       requests[requestCount] = newRequest;
       emit RequestCreated(msg.sender,requestCount,deadline,0,requests[requestCount].miniReputation,requests[requestCount].remuneration,requests[requestCount].description,"",State.OPENED);
    }



//postuler
    function applyTo(uint _id)
    public
    isUser(msg.sender)
    isCompany(_id)
    isRequest(_id)
    requestState(_id,State.OPENED)
    {

        require(!requests[_id].candidates[msg.sender],"You are already candidate !");
        require(requests[_id].miniReputation<=users[msg.sender].reputation,"Reputation is not enought");
        requests[_id].candidates[msg.sender]=true;
        emit Application(_id,msg.sender,users[msg.sender].reputation);
    }


//acceptOffer
    function acceptOffer(uint _id,address _add)
    public
    isRequest(_id)
    requestState (_id,State.OPENED)
    isCandidate(_id,_add)
    nextRequestState(_id,State.ONGOING)
    {
        require(requests[_id].company==msg.sender,"You are not the company !");
        requests[_id].startTime = now;
        requests[_id].deadline=requests[_id].deadline+requests[_id].startTime;
        requests[_id].accepted[_add] =true;   
         emit OfferAccepted(_id,_add);
    }

//delivery

    function delivery(uint _id,string memory _url)
    public
    isAccepted(_id,msg.sender)
    isRequest(_id)
    requestState (_id,State.ONGOING)
    isInTime(_id)
    nextRequestState(_id,State.CLOSED)
    {
        requests[_id].url = _url;
        users[msg.sender].reputation++;
        uint remuneration = requests[_id].remuneration;
       // address company = requests[_id].company;
        balances[owner]=balances[owner].sub(remuneration);
        msg.sender.transfer(remuneration);
    }


    function sanction(uint _id, address _add)
    public
    isAccepted(_id,_add)
    isRequest(_id)
    requestState (_id,State.ONGOING)
    afterDeadline(_id)
    nextRequestState(_id,State.CLOSED)
    {
        require(requests[_id].company==msg.sender,"You are not the company !");
        users[_add].reputation--;
    }

}
```

Comment: Line number missing from the error and the source code - impossible to say where the error happened, so very difficult to tell what is wrong. Please edit your question and include relevant context so that readers can know where the error happes.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a missing semicolon and/or parenthesis. There is just a code-dump here, without even specifying which line of code is the reason for the error (which can be easily inferred from the error-message). It is therefore a low-quality question with no contribution to other readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code perfectly compile and deployed in my Ganache network, after making few changes use any text editor to compare the changes.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.6.8;


import "@openzeppelin/contracts/math/Math.sol";

contract Marketplace {

 //using SafeMath for uint;

    struct User {
        uint reputation;
        string name;
        bool isUser;
    }

    struct Request {
            address company;
            uint id;
            uint deadline; //delai
            uint startTime;
            uint miniReputation;
            uint remuneration;
            string description;
            string url;
            State state;
            mapping(address=>bool) accepted;
            mapping(address=>bool) candidates;
    }

    address owner;
    mapping (address => uint) public balances;
    mapping(address => User) public users;
    mapping(uint => Request) public requests;
   // mapping(uint=>mapping(address=>bool))public candidates;


    uint requestCount;
    uint decimal=100;
    uint cost=102;

    enum State{OPENED,ONGOING,CLOSED}

    event UserCreated(address _add,uint _reputation, string  _name, bool _isUser);
    event RequestCreated(address _add, uint _id, uint _deadline, uint _startTime,
    uint _miniReputation, uint _cost, string _description,
    string _url, State _state);
    event Application(uint _id,address _add,uint _reputation);
    event OfferAccepted(uint _id,address _add);

    constructor() public{
        owner = msg.sender;
        requestCount;
    }

   modifier requestState  (uint _id, State _state) {
            require(requests[_id].state==_state,"request is not accessible");
            _;
        }

    modifier nextRequestState
        (uint _id, State _state)
        {
            updateState(_id, _state);
         _;

        }

    modifier isUser
        (address _add)
        {
            require(_add!=address(0),"You are the 0 address");
            require(users[_add].isUser,"You are not a user !");
            _;
        }

    modifier isRequest
        (uint _id)
        {
            require(requests[_id].id > 0,"The request does not exist !");
            _;
        }


    modifier isCandidate
        (uint _id,address _add)
        {
            require(_add!=address(0),"You are the 0 address");
            require(requests[_id].candidates[_add],"You are not a candidate !");
            _;
        }


    modifier isCompany
        (uint _id)
        {
            require(msg.sender!=address(0),"You are the 0 address");
            require(requests[_id].company!=msg.sender,"You are the company !");
            _;
        }

    modifier isAccepted
        (uint _id,address _add)
        {
            require(_add!=address(0),"You are the 0 address");
            require(requests[_id].accepted[_add],"You are not accepted !");
            _;
        }

    modifier isInTime (uint _id)
    {
      require(requests[_id].startTime<=now && requests[_id].deadline>=now,"You are not in time");  
      _;
    }

    modifier afterDeadline
    (uint _id)
    {
        require(requests[_id].deadline < now,"The deadline is not reached !");
        _;
    }

    function  updateState(uint _id,State _state) internal{
        requests[_id].state = _state;
    }

//s'inscrire
    function inscription (string memory _name, uint _reputation) public 
    {
        require(!users[msg.sender].isUser, "You are already user !");
        require(bytes(_name).length>0,"the name is not valid");
        require(_reputation>=1,"the reputation is not valid");
        User memory newUser = User(_reputation,_name,true);
        users[msg.sender] = newUser;
        emit UserCreated(msg.sender,_reputation,_name,true);
    }

    //ajouter demande
    function addRequest
    (string calldata _description,
    uint _miniReputation,
    uint _deadline,
    uint _remuneration)
    external
    payable
    isUser(msg.sender)
    {
        //verifier qu'on a bien une description 
        require(bytes(_description).length>0,"The description is not valid !");
        //verifier que la reputation est sup à 1
        require(_miniReputation>1,"miniReputation is not valid");
        //verifier que la durée est bien plus superieur à 0
        require(_deadline>0,"The deadline is not valid");
        //verifier si on a assez de Wei
        uint256 _amount = (_remuneration * cost) / (decimal);
        require(msg.value >= _amount,"not enough of Wei");
        requestCount++;
        balances [owner]=balances [owner] + (msg.value);
       uint deadline = _deadline * 1 days;
       Request memory newRequest = Request(msg.sender,requestCount,deadline,0,_miniReputation,_remuneration,_description,"",State.OPENED);
       requests[requestCount] = newRequest;
       emit RequestCreated(msg.sender,requestCount,deadline,0,requests[requestCount].miniReputation,requests[requestCount].remuneration,requests[requestCount].description,"",State.OPENED);
    }



//postuler
    function applyTo(uint _id)
    public
    isUser(msg.sender)
    isCompany(_id)
    isRequest(_id)
    requestState(_id,State.OPENED)
    {

        require(!requests[_id].candidates[msg.sender],"You are already candidate !");
        require(requests[_id].miniReputation<=users[msg.sender].reputation,"Reputation is not enought");
        requests[_id].candidates[msg.sender]=true;
        emit Application(_id,msg.sender,users[msg.sender].reputation);
    }


//acceptOffer
    function acceptOffer(uint _id,address _add)
    public
    isRequest(_id)
    requestState (_id,State.OPENED)
    isCandidate(_id,_add)
    nextRequestState(_id,State.ONGOING)
    {
        require(requests[_id].company==msg.sender,"You are not the company !");
        requests[_id].startTime = now;
        requests[_id].deadline=requests[_id].deadline+requests[_id].startTime;
        requests[_id].accepted[_add] =true;   
         emit OfferAccepted(_id,_add);
    }

//delivery

    function delivery(uint _id,string memory _url)
    public
    isAccepted(_id,msg.sender)
    isRequest(_id)
    requestState (_id,State.ONGOING)
    isInTime(_id)
    nextRequestState(_id,State.CLOSED)
    {
        requests[_id].url = _url;
        users[msg.sender].reputation++;
        uint remuneration = requests[_id].remuneration;
       // address company = requests[_id].company;
        balances[owner]=balances[owner] - (remuneration);
        msg.sender.transfer(remuneration);
    }


    function sanction(uint _id, address _add)
    public
    isAccepted(_id,_add)
    isRequest(_id)
    requestState (_id,State.ONGOING)
    afterDeadline(_id)
    nextRequestState(_id,State.CLOSED)
    {
        require(requests[_id].company==msg.sender,"You are not the company !");
        users[_add].reputation--;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply i compiled my code only with the network of truffle develop, but i will compile with the Ganache network to check the difference